Is there a way in Perforce Swarm to see which reviews I am the "required reviewer"
My team has many people asking for reviews and we get emails when code is ready to review, so I don't look at all the reviews - there are too many - and many are not in my area's of expertise.
I would like to be able to see if there are any open reviews that I am the required reviewer on - I don't want to have to open each review to check.
How can I get a list of the code reviews I am the required reviewer on?
